# Allow only 2 concurrect cronjobs kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

Is there a way to allow cronjobs to run at maximum 2 jobs at the same time? I can easily set this to 1 by setting `concurrencyPolicy: Forbid`. And if I set `concurrencyPolicy: Allow` then it could go to more than 2 - but I want this to be limited to exactly 2 maximum and if greater should never start.

For example I have a `*/5 * * * *` schedule; at minute 0 we have a job, at minute 5 we have a job (and the job at minute 0 is still running) but at minute 10 (job 0 and 5 [2 jobs] are still running) we should block the job being created.

Comment: I believe you cannot do that with native kubernetes `cronjob`.

Answer (score -1):

With the `.spec.completions` the maximum number of pods you need to run for a job can be set.

With the `.spec.parallelism` the number of parallel pods can be set.
For [more](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#writing-a-job-spec) information.

Comment: How using these 2 parameters you would set concurrency that takes into account runs from multiple schedules? In other words, what values would allow "to run at maximum 2 jobs at the same time"?

Comment: Both `2` should work.

Comment: Don't they both control the completion and parallelism (read it as "number of pods") **strictly for one current job only**? The question is how to limit number of active jobs for cronjob, not pods per one job.

Comment: Yes. `cronjob` creates job and `job` creates the workload(pods). In the case you mentioned, you could simply create the job with the cronjob and control the parallelism in the job definition.

Comment: Re-read the question again: the question is how to limit **number of jobs**, not number of pods. OP has only 1 pod per job, so `completions` and `parallelism` makes no sense.